# StackOverflowError when using JsonBuilder's toPrettyString

Tags: jenkins, groovy, httprequest

I have the following code.
It receives filenames available locally in the Jenkins workspace, reads the files, and attempts sending their contents to an endpoint.

For `service-configuration.json` this works. However, for the remaining files it fails with a StackOverflowError...

```
// Update Service configuration.
serviceJson = readJSON file: "service-configuration.json"

response = httpRequest validResponseCodes: "100:504", acceptType: "APPLICATION_JSON", contentType: "APPLICATION_JSON", customHeaders: [[name: 'Authorization', value: iamToken]], httpMode: "PUT", requestBody: new JsonBuilder(serviceJson).toPrettyString(), url: GlobalCatalog.service
if (response.status != 200) {
  println "Failure: ${response.status} ${response.content}"
  currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
  error "Failed uploading Global Catalog entry."
}

// Update Plans and their Deployments configurations.
GlobalCatalog.plans.each { plan ->
  planJson = readJSON file: "${plan.planName}-plan-configuration.json"

  response = httpRequest validResponseCodes: "100:504", acceptType: "APPLICATION_JSON", contentType: "APPLICATION_JSON", customHeaders: [[name: 'Authorization', value: iamToken]], httpMode: "PUT", requestBody: new JsonBuilder(planJson).toPrettyString(), url: plan.url
  if (response.status != 200) {
    println "Failure: ${response.status} ${response.content}"
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    error "Failed uploading Global Catalog entry."
  } else {
    plan.deployments.each { deployment ->
      deploymentJson = readJSON file: "${plan.planName}-${deployment.region}-deployment-configuration.json"

      response = httpRequest validResponseCodes: "100:504", acceptType: "APPLICATION_JSON", contentType: "APPLICATION_JSON", customHeaders: [[name: 'Authorization', value: iamToken]], httpMode: "PUT", requestBody: new JsonBuilder(deploymentJson).toPrettyString(), url: deployment.url    
      if (response.status != 200) {
        println "Failure: ${response.status} ${response.content}"
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        error "Failed uploading Global Catalog entry."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The StackOverflowError:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
```

Edit: if I use `toString()` instead, it works - but the encoding of the various language strings in the file is not kept...

Comment: You have somewhere recursive object reference.

Comment: I don't see declaration of the `depl` variable

Comment: Right, "depl" is just an omission in the copy/paste above. Fixed.

Comment: Strange. Could you share one of json that fails? Could you try http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonOutput.html#prettyPrint(java.lang.String) without parsing it?

Comment: @daggett here is a redacted version of the JSON: https://pastebin.com/LQr1Nvyy

Comment: Also, if I use `toString()` instead, it works - but the encoding of the various language strings in the file is not kept...

Comment: Encoding is another question. groovy json encodes all non-latin letters to \uHHH format - and it's ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195905/discussion-between-idan-adar-and-daggett).

Comment: sonOutput.prettyPrint(planJson) seems to work

Comment: I see this type of issue _extensively_ in Jenkins. If I have `String myJsonString = getString(); println(toJson(fromJson(myJsonString)))`, I will often get stack overflow errors, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was suggested in the comments, using `JsonOutput.prettyPrint(myProp)` worked much better than `new JsonBuilder(myProp).toPrettyString()` although I am not sure why...